# Python Idle Starts With "No Subprocess" so running script freeze

Tags: python, windows, shell, python-idle

I had no problems selecting "run" from a script opened with idle before Windows Update made updates.

For some reason, now when I select "run", the new live idle window freezes up and the script window freezes up.  This did not occur before updates but from what I can see, none of the updates would effect idle or python.

The script seems to run but the windows (both) are frozen...this never happened before.

I now get this message when using sys.exit to close the running script, "do you want to exit altogether?"  I NEVER got that message before something is really messed up.  If I select yes, then all idle windows close and that's not what I want!

I noticed idle says "No Subprocess" when the live window opens....but my script indeed creates threads and "chit"  (lol, excuse the pun)

IDLE: 2.7, python 2.7

Windows 7 64 bit
AMD chipset
Nivida Graphics
HP Desktop
Quadcore

---------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------

When I open my script by right clicking and selecting "open with idle", I get the above issues.

I just opened idle from a shortcut instead, which opened the live window.  From there I selected New File from the top menu and opened my script file.

Everything ran like before the issues....?

So why all of a sudden selecting "edit with idle" is acting like I'm opening idle with the "-n" argument or something?

Comment: This issue is off-topic for StackOverflow as it is about system administration more than about writing code.  I suggest posting to https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list (mirrored as newsgroup gmane.comp.python.general at news.gmane.org).  Subscription not required.

Comment: Some questions in the meanwhile.  Are you running the latest 2.7 release *(.14)?  If MS invalidated 2.7's `Open with IDLE`, a fix might be possible for future release, but not before.  If you have or install 3.6.3 or even 3.7.0a3, do you have the same issue?  I believe the `Open with ...` code has been rewritten to work better with current Windows.  By 'live window', do you mean the interactive Shell window?  (I never use `Open with` but others have had various problems on Windows.  I use the Recent Files list or navigate within the Open File dialog.)